# Matrix divide by zero warning

Tags: numpy, matrix, divide-by-zero

I am new in Python and I am facing the following error in the code:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.empty([2, 2], dtype = float)
Z = np.empty([2, 2], dtype = float)
Z = [[2.0, 0.0],  [0.0, 3.0]]
A = [[1, -1], [1, -2]]

print(np.divide(A, np.power(Z, 2)))
```

These code gives the following result:

```
[[ 0.25  -inf], [inf -0.22222222]]
```

But I know, using a calculator, that the correct answer should be:

```
[[ 0.25   -0.25], [ 0.111111 -0.22222222]]
```

In short, thhis operation gives me the following error:
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide

Comment: How did you get the output from the calculator? seems the calculator is calculating something else.

Comment: When you use `Z = [[2.0, 0.0],  [0.0, 3.0]]` and `A = [[1, -1], [1, -2]]` you are setting `A` and `Z` to type list. I'd rather just initialize the array's using `np.array([[...], [...]], dtype=float)`

Comment: Hi @MichaelRichardson. I followed your suggestion, but the error remains.

Answer (score 0):

You are element-wise dividing `A` by `Z^2`:

A:

```
[[1, -1], [1, -2]]
```

Z^2:

```
[[4.0, 0.0],  [0.0, 9.0]]
```

A/Z^2:

```
[[ 0.25  -inf], [inf -0.22222222]]
```

The output is correct. You receive the warning (and not an error) of division by 0 because there are 0s in Z^2 in denominator that result in `inf`s in output. Your calculator output is not what your code does.

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply. In this case, what would be your suggestion, to get the real numbers labeled as "inf"?

Comment: @CosmeRodolfoSantos What is your desired output? In other words, what are you trying to calculate?